# Как реализовать Generating path в Unity?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d

Нужно реализовать генерацию пути с развилкой (то что нужно мне указано на изображении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам саму карту генерировать или найти путь по ней?

Comment: саму карту генерировать

Comment: Ну идея проста - берем две точки, генерируем один путь, потом берем два участка этой тропки и генерируем другой путь между ними. Profit